# Django merge duplicate rows

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a table like this.

```
id|name                 |user_id     |amount|
--|---------------------|------------|------|
 1|Name1                |1           |     4|
 2|Name1                |1           |     7|
 3|Name2                |1           |     5|
```

I want to merge rows that have the same `name` and `user_id` and that should look like this:

```
id|name                 |user_id     |amount|
--|---------------------|------------|------|
 1|Name1                |1           |    11|
 2|Name2                |1           |     5|
```

`Django ver = 3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to merge literally, but you can use `GROUP BY` for it:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

YourModel.objects.values('name', 'user_id').annotate(total=Sum('amount')).values('name', 'user_id', 'total')
```

More infromation can be found in [documentation of `values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values).